# Getting Empty Object in postman

Tags: c#, .net

i get empty object and 200 response when i try to get the movies which are bought,
i can buy the movie but can not show it

here is the repository function

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<CartItem>> CartItems(int UserId)
        {
            return await (from cart in this.context.Cart
                          join cartItem in this.context.CartItem
                          on cart.Id equals cartItem.CartId
                          where cart.UserId == UserId
                          select new CartItem
                          {
                              Id = cartItem.Id,
                              MovieId = cartItem.MovieId,
                              mengde = cartItem.mengde,
                              CartId = cartItem.CartId,
                          }).ToListAsync();



        }
```

and the controller

```
   
        [HttpGet("CurrentUser")]
        public int GetLoggetInUserId()
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("UserId"));
            return id;
        }


    


        [HttpGet("GetItems")]
       
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CartItemDTO>>> CartItems()
        {
            
            try
            {
                int userId = GetLoggetInUserId();
                // here we returned cartItem object
                var cartItems = await this.shoping.CartItems(userId);

                if (cartItems == null)
                {
                    
                    return NoContent();
                }

                
                var movies = await this.repository.GetAll();

              
             
                if (movies == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No products exist in the system");
                }

                var UserCartItems = cartItems.ConvertToDto(movies);
               
                return Ok(UserCartItems);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "the GET call to /api/user fieled");
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    ex.Message);

            }
            

        }
```

and the interface

```
 public interface IShoping
    {
        
      
        Task<CartItem> AddItem(CartItemToAddDto cartItemToAddDto);
        Task<CartItem> DeleteItem(int Id);
        Task<CartItem> GetItem(int id);
        Task<IEnumerable<CartItem>> CartItems(int UserId);
        Task<CartItem> UpdateItem(int Id, CartItemMengdeUpdate cartItemMengdeUpdate);
```

the buy function works but when i try to get all the bought movies i get an empty object
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/boAYK.png)

Comment: are you sure that you are getting logged user id?

Comment: or maybe you are getting user id, but there are not any records for this user

Comment: do you mean the log in and register function?  i have them and they works fine

Comment: and the logged in user works also in postman

Comment: I mean if GetLoggetInUserId returns correct id, that has CartItems in the db

Comment: yes it do, i test it now

Comment: maybe there is something with your join? are you sure you don't need left join or sth like this?

Comment: url in image is wrong